# pentaho cde export button component with password protection

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I am using pentaho CDE - Export Component to download my data in CSV format.

I want to set password protected csv file .How can i do this using export component in pentaho cde.

Regards,
Kavitha S

Answer (score 0):

You can't password-protect plain text files. You can ZIP it and password protect the ZIP, or encrypt its contents, but cannot password protect the file itself as you would do with an Excel file for example.

And the CDE export component doesn't support either of those options. Your best option is to add a custom action to a button that calls a PDI transformation that runs the query, saves it as a CSV and then ZIPs it in a password protected archive; or just write the output as a password protected XLS file. But you'd have to develop that solution, as far as I know there isn't anything you can use out of the box.